# Python object has no object has no attribute 'asyncio'?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, websocket, python-asyncio

I am trying to connect two nodes via WebSocket API but I have trouble letting the kern object do the API call. And I am also trying to let the node to node communication work in another thread. Or should I just discard oop? I think without oop everything should work just fine. I am new to python. Any ideas?

Here is my code

```
import boto3
import os
import requests
from botocore.handlers import disable_signing
import asyncio
import websockets
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
import logging
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from flask import Flask, request
import time
import threading



ID = "xxxx"
device_name="node1"
loop=0



app = Flask(__name__)
# @app.route('/post', methods=['POST'])
class Kern:
    def __init__(self):
        self.leader=0
        self.loop=0

    def download_blob_to_file(self,blob_service_client: BlobServiceClient, container_name, bolb):
        blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=bolb)
        with open(file=os.path.join('/home/tian0138/csci-5105/Research', bolb), mode="wb") as sample_blob:
            download_stream = blob_client.download_blob()
            sample_blob.write(download_stream.readall())
    def handle_post_request(self,response):
        # Get the data from the request body
        ID = response["ID"]
        container = response["container"]
        bolb = response["bolb"]
        account_name = response["account_name"]
        account_url = "https://{}.blob.core.windows.net".format(account_name)
        blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=account_url)
        self.download_blob_to_file(blob_service_client,container,bolb)
        # Process the data...
        return 'Success'

    def boot(self):
        url = 'http://localhost:8000/post'
        data = {"ID": ID, "device_name": device_name}
        response = requests.post(url, data=data)
        response = response.json()
        print(response)
        self.handle_post_request(response)

    async def node_heartbeat_response(self,websocket):
        async for message in websocket:
            components=message.split('!')
            if len(components)==1:#ping
                ping=components[0]
                print(ping)
                response="pong"
            else:
                response="wrong"
            expiration=500
            await websocket.send(response)

    async def node_heartbeat(self):#leader send 
        time.sleep(2)
        async with websockets.connect("ws://localhost:8765",ping_interval=None) as websocket:
            await websocket.send("ping") 
            result = await websocket.recv()
            print(result)

    async def connect_follower_heart(self):# 
        async with websockets.serve(self.node_heartbeat_response, "localhost", 8765,ping_interval=None):
            await asyncio.Future()  # run forever

k1=Kern()
k1.boot()
decision = input("Leader?")
if decision=="leader":
    print("in leader")
    k1.leader=1
    leader_heartbeat = threading.Thread(target=k1.asyncio.run(node_heartbeat))
    leader_heartbeat.start()
else:
    follower_thread = threading.Thread(target=k1.asyncio.run(connect_follower_heart))
    follower_thread.start()
while True:
    k1.loop=k1.loop+1
leader_heartbeat.join()
follower_thread.join()
```

I didn't similar usage or should I try another way?

Comment: `k1` is an instance of Kern, which has no `asyncio` attribute at all. Did you mean to call `asyncio.run(k1.node_heartbeat)`? There are also likely issues with running async tasks in threads ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68150174/5774952), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67525748/5774952)), but that's a separate issue.

Comment: Could it be that the while loop never breaks? It seems to me that you'll get stuck doing k1.loop = k1.loop + 1 and never get to the joins.

Also, what are you trying to do at a higher level? This seems like very complicated code if you're new to Python, there is probably a simpler way of achieving whatever you're trying to achieve!